# How can I change editors to Eds. in bibliography?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, apa-style, bibdesk

I use `\bibliographystyle{apalike-fr}`. I use BibDesk. In the references I get this:
[image]

How can I change change "éditeurs" into "Eds." and "Ed." if single editor ?

Comment: `pp.` is not a French abbreviation. It should always be `p.`, whether singular or plural. That said, it's easier to do if you use `biblatex` with option `style=apa`.

Comment: I don't use 'biblatex', I don't even know what it is I'll google it thanks.

Comment: If you want to submit to a journal, ask the editors for advice. Most likely, they don't allow `biblatex`.

Comment: No it is a dissertation. It is fine like this I just want to change éditeurs to Eds.

Answer (score 1):

Just open the [apalike-fr.bst](http://barthes.ens.fr/cours/informatique-pour-litteraires/apalike-fr.bst) file and replace the code :

```
FUNCTION{fr.editeur}{       %% ", \'editeur" au singulier, ou " (\'editeur)"...
", \'editeur"
}
```

by

```
FUNCTION{fr.editeur}{       %% ", \'editeur" au singulier, ou " (\'editeur)"...
", Ed."
}
```

and also replace the code

```
FUNCTION{fr.editeurs}{      %% ", \'editeurs" au pluriel, ou " (\'editeurs)"...
", \'editeurs"
}
```

by

```
FUNCTION{fr.editeurs}{      %% ", \'editeurs" au pluriel, ou " (\'editeurs)"...
", Eds."
}
```

Comment: ... and after changing the file content, save it under a different name to comply with the licence of latex.

Comment: Thank you! I use Texpad for Mac and I can't find this file apelike-fr.bst. Where can I find it?

Comment: @user105139 just click on `apalike-fr.bst` in the above answer.

Comment: @user105139, did this fix your problem ?

Comment: I can open the URL but I have no idea what to do about it. I can't find the .bst file in my computer since I use Texpad for Mac, I found the folder by the terminal, but I might need to create that?

Comment: @user105139, ok, download the modified version from here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vwsladsysxhqkgz/mon-apalike-fr.bst?dl=0. Don'tt forget to replace `\bibliographystyle{apalike-fr}` by `\bibliographystyle{mon-apalike-fr}`

Comment: @user105139, you are welcome, do not hesitate to tell me if this does not work properly.